# Problem with tracing over the environment and obtaining reduced density operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, measurement-problem, decoherence

[image]

I'm reading an article by Bas Henson given [here](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/5439/1/Decoherence_Essay_arXiv_version.pdf).

On page 25 he deals with the double slit experiment

Given the wavefunction which is his equation 1.75, he claims he has traced over the environment to get the reduced density operator 
of eqn 1.76.
 I can get to his answer by using the tracing method of eqn 1.16 on page 9 of his paper but if instead, I form the full density operator from eqn 1.75 and then trace over it with both $|e_1\rangle$ and $|e_2\rangle$  to get the reduced (particle) density matrix eqn 1.76 then by computing the  trace this long way round, I get these two extra terms:

$$\frac{1}{2}|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1| \langle e_1|e_2\rangle\langle e_2|e_1\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2| \langle e_1|e_2\rangle\langle e_2|e_1\rangle$$

I cannot assume that any environment inner products go to zero  since he does not assume this in his final equation 1.76.

Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?
Maybe the workings in the image will help.  If I trace over the expression on line three using the method of eqn 1.16 on page 9 then I quickly get the answer he gives as eqn 1.76. But tracing over the long way as I've done as from line five should give the right answer.

Comment: [Here is the notation we use here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I've edited the LaTeX three times to correctly write the bras and kets. In subsequent edits, **be sure to not reverse the fixes.** Thanks.

Comment: Please list the relevant equations here for ease of read and to combat link rot.

Comment: How do you get these extra terms? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is arising since you are trying to take the trace in a non-orthonormal basis including both $|e_1\rangle$ and $|e_2\rangle$. If $A$ is an operator, the trace of the matrix
$$A_{mn}\equiv \langle e_m|A|e_n\rangle$$
is not invariant under *any* basis $|e_m\rangle$. If this is the orthonormal eigenbasis, the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. Any other orthonormal basis is related to the eigenbasis by a unitary transformation, and you can show easily that this gives you the same trace. But the transformation to a general basis is not unitary, and does not give you the same trace.

So the trace of both projection operators $|e_1\rangle\langle e_1|,|e_2\rangle\langle e_2|$ is $1$. Just pick an orthonormal basis that contains $|e_1\rangle$ but not $|e_2\rangle$ and vice versa.

Similarly the trace of $|e_1\rangle\langle e_2|$ is $\langle e_2|e_1\rangle$, as you can see by using either of the two orthonormal bases just mentioned (and it's the same in any other orthonormal basis, of course).

Comment: Or one can just use cyclicity of the trace to show $\mathrm{tr}(\vert a\rangle\langle b\vert)=\langle b \vert a \rangle$.